# Borland BCB5 TInifile ignores Quotation Marks with Readstring()?

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder, ini, vcl

I am not quite familar with Borland C++ Builder 5 and am stuck with an issue.

I have an INI file with:

```
[Section1]
Ident1="myUser1"
Ident2=myPassword
```

I read the Username and Password values with this code:

```
{
auto_ptr<TIniFile> ifile(new TIniFile(myinifile));
AnsiString InternalUser= ifile->ReadString("Section1", "Ident1", "Defaultuser");
AnsiString InternalPassword= ifile->ReadString("Section1", "Ident2","Defaultpassword");
}
```

Here is the function declaration:

```
virtual AnsiString __fastcall ReadString(const AnsiString Section, const AnsiString Ident, const AnsiString Default);
```

Expected Output:

```
Ident1="myUser1" (with ")
Ident2=myPassword
```

Actual Output:

```
Ident1=myUser1 (without ")
Ident2=myPassword
```

While trying to debug this, I get a lot of Delphi system calls I dont know and cant find documentation for, like `LStrToPChar`, `LStrClr`, etc.

I was expecting some sort of `Trim()` but was wrong.

Can somebody enlighten me on the problem, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This class is a wrapper around the long since deprecated Windows INI file API. The function that reads the values is [`GetPrivateProfileString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353.aspx) and its documentation says:

> If the string associated with lpKeyName is enclosed in single or double quotation marks, the marks are discarded when the GetPrivateProfileString function retrieves the string.

Hence the behaviour that you observe.

Comment: If you don't like this behavior, you can use `TMemIniFile` instead of `TIniFile`.  `TMemIniFile` does not use Microsoft's PrivateProfile API, it parses the INI data manually, and preserves quotes.

Comment: I agree completely I stopped using the WinAPI ini interface a long time ago it was so slooow. I ended up coding my own Class (based on AnsiString) that reads entire ini recognize its structure in form of list of sections  preserving also any rems. And it was around 1000x faster then WinAPI (both read and write) for ini file around 10KB with multiple sections I am bound to use because of my work. WinAPI loaded it few seconds my class got  it in few milliseconds instead.

Comment: Deprecated, but still used by MS themselves inculding WIn10. Just look out for `desktop.ini` files or google for `ShellClassInfo`.

Comment: @JensG How can you tell that MS is using their own deprecated API for INI files. I'd be astounded if they were. I think it unlikely that they would wish to be bound by all the compat shims and the performance issues with that API. It's quite possible to work with INI files and not use that API.

Comment: Many THX guys! I marked DavidHeffernans post as acceptet Answer. But also THX to @Remy Lebau for saving me from writing a Workaround.
I hope the Q wasnt too noobish, cause i would have never come to this conclusion.

Comment: @c0pyc4t: Your question was just fine.

Comment: @David: shell32.dll imports `WritePrivateProfileStringW` and 5 other `get*Profile*` functions from `API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL`. But that does not prove anything, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be not a problem caused by Borland, rather behaviour of the underlying Windows API routines. A quick check using MSVC gives the same result.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{    
    TCHAR buf[400];
    GetPrivateProfileString( _T("Test"), _T("Test"), _T("Default"), &buf[0], 400, _T("test.ini"));
    _tprintf(_T("%s\n"),&buf);

    return 0;
}
```

The INI file:

```
[Test]
Test="string with quotes"
```

Result:

```
string with quotes
```

This is [documented behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353.aspx):

> If the string associated with lpKeyName is enclosed in single or double quotation marks, the marks are discarded when the GetPrivateProfileString function retrieves the string.

Comment: A line in an INI file that begins with a `;` is a comment. Why do you think it is a bug for the API to allow INI creators to write comments to the file?

Comment: @Remy: Maybe the example was not perfect. If you play around with that API you will find some more "interesting" behaviour. For example, try to use [] inside a section name. That is clearly invalid, but write succeeds. I'm sure you will come up with a valid use case for that as well, do you? :-). Anyway, I removed it as it does not add much value to the question. Thanks for the docs pointer, BTW.